# How to return apostrophe when using Google Translate API for Android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-translate

I have an Android application that uses Google Translate API.
Everything works great, including when I tried to translate phrases that include apostrophe like "We've eaten" to Spanish.

However, problems occur when the translation result I should be getting back contains an apostrophe. For example, when I translate a Spanish phrase, "A ver", into English, it returns "Let&#39s see" with a ";" after "9". It seems like whenever I have a phrase that should return an apostrophe, it returns "&#39" with a ";" after "9". (Not placing ";" after "9" because it gets converted to an apostrophe by stackoverflow).

I can think of a way to solve it. After I get the translation result, I can match the string for ""&#39" + ";" and replace it with an apostrophe.

However, I don't feel like this is the way I should approach it. It's very unlikely that a user will actually type in "&#39" as an input for translation, but hard coding a manual conversion like this seems like it might cause problems down the road. I'll love to hear your thoughts on this.

Please let me know how I should fix/approach this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct hard codding is not solution,
But you can convert this HTML entity back to apostrophe, by Using HTML classes provided already.

```
Html.fromHtml((String) "Let&#39;s see").toString()
```

Above code will convert any valid HTML entity.
I Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nakul! Everything seems to work fine. However, I don't understand why this is required. I'm parsing a JSON object, does that mean it's an HTML entity or is it an HTML entity because I'm getting the JSON object from an API? And if so, do I need to do this if I'm retrieving information from any API? Thanks again! Will like to understand the reasoning completely to avoid causing indirect errors by implementing this.

Comment: @CharlesLi I think, I depends upon which API you use, because Google Translate API can be used by websites too, that's the reason it is HTML friendly. That's what I think.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to add `&format=text` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guillaume.  For those using  php.

```
   $translation = $translate->translate($stringToTranslate, ['target' => $target, 'format' => 'text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895010/2037176). For those using go. (api v3)

```
req := &translatepb.TranslateTextRequest{
    MimeType: "text/plain", // add this line to request
}
```